# Not catching an error from async await despite using try catch blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a loop to get all whatsapp messages associated with given numbers, using whatsappweb-js. When there is error in this line "let chat = await client.getChatById(nums[i])" I'm not able to catch it , instead I get an error refering to the next line stating that "chat is not defined"! if I remove try catch I don't get any errors but the node js application just stop responding
note: client.getChatById(id) return a promise containing chat object.

```
function fetch(nums) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        try {
            let chat = await client.getChatById(nums[i])
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        };
    }
    return msgs = await chat.fetchMessages();
}
```

Comment: You're declaring `chat` inside the try so it's not available outside due to scope.

Comment: The line with the error is outside the `try`.

Comment: You need to add async, as in `async function fetch(nums)`, but that may not be the only issue

Comment: @AndyRay That must be a copying error (like the missing close brace), because otherwise it wouldn't even run.

Comment: though with a return inside the loop it's only going to run once

Answer (score 1):

The code that uses `chat` needs to be inside the `try` block. This is needed for scoping reasons, and also because it doesn't make sense to use `chat` if the call failed.

Also, you shouldn't have `return` inside the loop, since you want to collect the results from all the chats. Declare an array to hold them, add to the array in the loop, then return at the end.

```js
async function fetch(nums) {
  let msgs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    try {
      let chat = await client.getChatById(nums[i]);
      msgs = msgs.concat(await chat.fetchMessages());
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`while fetching ${nums[i]}`, err)
    };
  }
  return msgs;
}
```

Comment: Better answer than mine :) - I couldn't figure out how to explain it properly.

Comment: Thank you ,a curly bracket got lost , I'm in fact returining msgs outside loop.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, either, because then `chat` only contains the result from the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the return:

```
    function fetch(nums) {
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    try {
      let chat = await client.getChatById(nums[i])
      return msgs = await chat.fetchMessages();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }; 
  }
```

Your putting your `chat` variable outside the try/catch, so it wouldn't know what the variable is.